# Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, fstab

Hello I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu and Linux. I am currently running a Windows 10 and Ubuntu partition.My version of Ubuntu is 20.04.4. After searching the internet the must common fix for my problem seems to be to update the UUID in the file /etc/fstab to match the UUID given by sudo blkid. However in my case both UUID's are the same. Confused about what to do next.

Here is the output from cat /etc/fstab.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# Use 'blkid' to print universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# (file system) (mount print)  (type)  (options)   (Dump)  (pass)
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=9e23567d-55ad-4455-aa65-cecbba883fcc /    ext4  errors=remount-ro 0   1
# /boot/efi was on dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=D5C8-6AAE /boot/efi   vfat  umask=0077  0   1
/swapfile                        none     swap  sw    O   O
```

Output from running sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="9e23567d-55ad-4455-aa65-cecbba883fcc" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000010b0-05"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop29: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop28: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda2: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="DA6463286463071B" TYPE="nfts" PARTUUID="000010b0-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="D5C8-6AAE" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000010b0-03"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="A8E65F59E65F26BA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="000010b-01"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
```

These are the errors displayed on booting Ubuntu:

```
[    0.11447] x/86: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 2509484/12222464 files, 26749471/48861696 blocks
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/D5C8-6AAE.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/D5C8-6AAE.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems
[FAILED] Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
```

####Output from running sudo fdisk -l | sed -e '/Disk /dev/loop/,+5d' ####

```
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary. Disk /dev/sda: 465.78GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPCX-2

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000010b0

|Device   |Boot |Start |End |Sectors |Size |Id |Type |
|/dev/sda1|*    |2048  |1187|1185792 |579M |7  |HPFS/|
|         |     |      |839 |        |     |   |NTFS/|
|         |     |      |    |        |     |   |exFAT|
|---------|-----|------|----|--------|-----|---|-----|
|/dev/sda2|     |118784|5848|58363651|278.3|7  |HPFS/|
|         |     |0     |2435|1       |G    |   |NTFS/|
|         |     |      |0   |        |     |   |exFAT|
|---------|-----|------|----|--------|-----|---|-----|
|/dev/sda3|     |584824|5858|1050624 |513M |b  |W95 F|
|         |     |832   |7545|        |     |   |AT32 |
|         |     |      |5   |        |     |   |     |
|---------|-----|------|----|--------|-----|---|-----|
|/dev/sda4|     |58587 |9767|39089357|186.4|5  |Exten|
|         |     |7502  |7107|0       |G    |   |ded  |
|         |     |      |1   |        |     |   |     |
|---------|-----|------|----|--------|-----|---|-----|
|/dev/sda5|     |58587 |9767|39089356|186.4|83 |Linux|
|         |     |7504  |7107|8       |G    |   |     |
|         |     |      |1   |        |     |   |     |
|---------|-----|------|----|--------|-----|---|-----|
```

##### Output from running sudo fdisk -l

[Beginning to loop 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Rys.jpg)

[Loop 3 to loop 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04Gs.jpg)

[Loop 7 to loop 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVYJF.jpg)(sdas are displayed here)

[Loop 11 to loop 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F1iG.jpg)

[Loop 18 to loop 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbZk3.jpg)

[Loop 22 to loop 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WW22.jpg)

###### Output from running lsblk -e 7 -0 name,fstype,size,fused,label,UUID,mount point

```
| NAME | FSTYPE | SIZE | FUSED | LABEL | UUID | MOUNTPOINT |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda   |        |465.8G|       |       |      |            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda1  |ntfs    |579M  |       |System |A8E65F|            |
|      |        |      |       |Reserve|59E65F|            |
|      |        |      |       |d      |26BA  |            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda2  |ntfs    |278.3G|       |       |DA6463|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |286463|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |071B  |            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda3  |vfat    |513M  |       |       |D5C8-6|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |AAE   |            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda4  |        |1k    |       |       |      |            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
|sda5  |ext4    |186.4G|97.7G  |       |9e2356|/           |
|      |        |      |       |       |7d-55a|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |d-4455|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |-aa65-|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |cecbba|            |
|      |        |      |       |       |883fcc|            |
|------|--------|------|-------|-------|------|------------|
```

Finally solved the issue:
I booted with a live usb and ran $`sudo fsck /dev/sda5` (my Linux partition, you can get yours by running sudo blkid, it's the one with type ext4) and ran boot repair recommended fix and then rebooted. Unfortunately Grub bootloader failed to run. So I booted with a live usb and ran $`sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` and then $`sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda5` to reinstall grub. I booted into my normal Ubuntu partition and all my errors were gone save one, "failed to load AppArmor profiles". And here I made a mistake, I followed the instructions here (https://francoconidi.it/solved-failed-to-start-load-apparmor-profiles-debian-10/) without fully understanding them, meaning I ran sudo purge snapd. Now, a lot of my applications are gone. However it did fix the AppArmor problem. And so I login and there were no errors, unfortunately no GUI either. I ran $`sudo apt list ubuntu-desktop` and found that it's not even installed. At that point I was ready to give up, I decided to just upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04 and hope all the missing packages will be reinstalled. I follow the instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) to chroot into my Ubuntu and upgrade and update everything. It doesn't completely upgrade because of a package (python3-cupshelpers), so I reinstall it, ubuntu-desktop (to be safe) and the xinit package. Then I booted into Ubuntu and I saw the GUI but I still ended up in ttyl. Running startx confirms the desktop is there but I needed the GUI to run by default. I rebooted and ran $`sudo systemctl isolate graphical`, that loaded the GUI and then in the terminal I ran $`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`. Rebooted. Works perfectly. Some of my applications, like Firefox, are gone though.

I apologise if I'm not making much sense, I am new to Linux so I'm not sure if I'm using correct terminology. Hope this is of help to you

Comment: A good place to start is to read the info at this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask There is no mention of a Ubuntu version in your question.

Comment: I just added that thanks. Do you have any other suggestions for how I could improve my question?

Comment: did you turn off fast boot in Windows?

Comment: No I didn't. I have not used windows in months. Windows works though. Thanks

Comment: @Esther just turned it off. Still does not boot.

Comment: UUID="9e23567-55ad-4455-aa65-cecbba88 **3fcc** " <- blkid, "UUID=9e23567d-55ad-4455-aa65-cecbba88 **f3** " in fstab - not equal. Do most likely need to be equal. but then your problem appears to be related to the 'efi' partition.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks, that was a mistake made while I was typing. The two are identical on my system

Comment: Can you get to do `sudo fdisk -l` on this disk? If yes, add it under a `<hr>` in your posting.

Comment: @Hannu Done. Images have been added

Comment: Ignore everything related to loop. Those are just your snap apps. In fact better to exclude those in various output. For example with lsblk the - e 7 will exclude snaps from list. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` You can try with & without as test. Other tools, may just need not copy & pasting that part of output.

Comment: You don't have to use UUID, you can specify by mount point. Have you tried changing to `/dev/sda3` to specify the disk for /boot/efi

Comment: @Crighton, No how do I do that?

Comment: @oldfred thanks, also added output from lsblk to the post

Comment: in fstab change `UUID=D5C8-6AAE /boot/efi   vfat  umask=0077  0   1` to `/dev/sda3/ /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1` although you might want to comment out the existing line with a `#` at the start and add the line below. easy to toggle between by commenting out the one you don't want active.

Comment: @Crighton Just tried that. It doesn't work

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm not sure I can suggest anything else.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your help. I think I'll try to run boot repair on an Ubuntu live usb then.